# convolving two functions in R

Tags: r

I want to convolve two functions in R. I started with `convolve(x,y,conj=TRUE, type="filter")`. I have two data files, both with 2 columns in it. In first data file I have columns called `lambda` and `flux`, while in other data file I have `lambda` and `SED`. My task is to convole this two functions, but I have different number of rows in my files and my `lambdas` are different.

Is there a possibility to convolve this functions in R. I cannot find a detailed description of the `x`,`y` used in `convolve(...)`. In examples I see only that ex. `x <- c(0,0,0,100,0,0,0)` and `y <- c(0,0,1, 2 ,1,0,0)/4`. 
Please, help me.

So more details. In first attempt, I did what follows:

```
f <- read.table('filtr.dat', header = T)
t <- read.table('SED.dat', header = T)
c <- subset(f, select = c(lam, flux))
d <- subset(t, select = c(lambda, SED))
cm <- as.matrix(c)
dm <- as.matrix(d)

con <- convolve(cm, dm, conj = TRUE, type = "filter")
print(con)
```

But as I understand it requires that filtr.dat and SED.dat must have the same length. My data file looks like (I only copy few rows from files):

```
filtr.dat # (lambda is in range ~2.5:6):

lambda flux
2.535182767624  3.570066318538e-06
2.540365535248  4.48837075718e-07
2.545548302872  3.41605613577e-07
2.550731070496  2.511449086162e-07
2.55591383812   2.628061357702e-07
2.561096605744  1.233503916449e-06
2.566279373368  5.77775456919e-06
2.571462140992  8.646391644909e-06
2.576644908616  7.251190600522e-06
2.58182767624   5.943718015666e-06
2.587010443864  4.797289817232e-06
2.592193211488  3.841451697128e-06
2.597375979112  3.145406005222e-06
2.602558746736  0.0001094945300261

SED.dat # (here I have more rows than in filtr.dat; lambda is in range ~0.1:15):

lambda SED
2.01837 2.6281e-15
2.02768 2.6100e-15
2.04174 2.4583e-15
2.05116 2.7267e-15
2.06063 2.9555e-15
2.07014 2.7966e-15
2.07970 2.7142e-15
2.08930 3.0664e-15
2.09411 4.1270e-15
2.09894 4.6734e-15
2.10863 4.3315e-15
2.11836 4.0892e-15
2.13304 4.4018e-15
2.14289 4.1080e-15
2.15278 3.7037e-15
2.16272 4.5148e-15
2.17270 4.5670e-15
2.18273 4.0517e-15
2.19281 4.0986e-15
2.20293 4.7823e-15
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (in your case this would include R code that we can run to replicate the sort of data you have).

Comment: I add more details above

Comment: what are your two functions? Convolution is defined on functions, but here you have two data.frames. What do you want to mean?

Comment: I want to convolve this data (if I can called it like this). When I draw this data I get two functions. I don't have equation for that functions I only have this data, which I want to convolve.